# Sent time in Outlook changes few seconds after item is sent

Tags: outlook, vsto, exchange-server, mapi

I am developing Outlook VSTO and using Items.ItemAdd event to track and process sent items. I know that it is unreliable, so I recheck items later by scanning sent folder and selected items.
The problem is that SentTime in ItemAdd handler and later in SelectionChange event differs a little (a minute and few seconds). Time in SelectionChange is smaller than in ItemAdd.
I found this old post, but without solution:
http://forums.msexchange.org/SentTime_differences_(PR_CLIENT_SUBMIT_TIME)/m_1800461424/tm.htm

I suppose that maybe when item is actually sent, Outlook silently updates it with a server timestamp that may be different. How can I detect this?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect a change later using `Items.ItemChange` event.